# How to start multiple audio tags simultaneously?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

I have several tracks to a song that I want to play together and be able to mute some and play others. So I need to be able to start them all at the same time. Right now, they all start slightly out of sync:

```
// Start playing
for ( i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
    tracks[i].audio.play();
}
```

Even this is apparently not fast enough to start them all at the same time.

Is there any way in javascript to guarantee that HTML5 audio tags will start playing simultaneously?

Comment: How about tying the play event to another (e.g. click) event?

Comment: I assume you are preloading all of the tracks and waiting for the 'canplaythrough' event to fire for each of them?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if you're already doing this, but Here's some sample code for preloading audio.

```
var audios = [];
var loading = 0;
AddNote("2C");
AddNote("2E");
AddNote("2G");
AddNote("3C");

function AddNote(name) {
    loading++;
    var audio = document.createElement("audio");
    audio.loop = true;
    audio.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function () {
        loading--;
        if (loading == 0) // All files are preloaded
            StartPlayingAll();
        }, false);
    audio.src = "piano/" + name + ".mp3";
    audios.push(audio);
}

function StartPlayingAll() {
    for (var i = 0; i < audios.length; i++)
        audios[i].play();
    }
}
```

The other thing you can try is setting `audio.currentTime` on each of the tracks to manually sync up the audio.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found a solution using the [Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API).

The problem is that the audio output has a delay of a few milliseconds, so it is impossible to start multiple audios at the same time. However, you can get around this by merging the audio sources into one using a [ChannelMergerNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChannelMergerNode). By putting [GainNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GainNode)s in between, you can control the volume of each audio source separately.

I wrote a simple javascript class for this. This is how you can use it:

```js
var audioMerger = new AudioMerger(["file1.ogg", "file2.mp3", "file3.mp3",
                                   "file4.ogg", "file5.mp3"]);
audioMerger.onBuffered(() => audioMerger.play());

// Make sure it's always in sync (delay should be less than 50 ms)
setInterval(() => {
  if (audioMerger.getDelay() >= 0.05) {
    audioMerger.setTime(audioMerger.getTime());
  }
}, 200);

// Set volume of 3rd audio to 50%
audioMerger.setVolume(0.5, 2);

// When you want to turn it off:
audioMerger.pause();
```

This code reduced the delay between the audios to less than 10 milliseconds in Firefox on my PC. This delay is so small you won't notice it. Unfortunately, it doesn't work in older browsers like Internet Explorer.

And here's the code for the class:

```js
class AudioMerger {
  constructor(files) {
    this.files = files;
    this.audios = files.map(file => new Audio(file));

    var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
    var ctx = new AudioContext();
    this.merger = ctx.createChannelMerger(this.audios.length);
    this.merger.connect(ctx.destination);

    this.gains = this.audios.map(audio => {
      var gain = ctx.createGain();
      var source = ctx.createMediaElementSource(audio);
      source.connect(gain);
      gain.connect(this.merger);
      return gain;
    });

    this.buffered = false;

    var load = files.length;
    this.audios.forEach(audio => {
      audio.addEventListener("canplaythrough", () => {
        load--;
        if (load === 0) {
          this.buffered = true;
          if (this.bufferCallback != null) this.bufferCallback();
        }
      });
    });
  }

  onBuffered(callback) {
    if (this.buffered) callback();
    else this.bufferCallback = callback;
  }

  play() {
    this.audios.forEach(audio => audio.play());
  }

  pause() {
    this.audios.forEach(audio => audio.pause());
  }

  getTime() {
    return this.audios[0].currentTime;
  }

  setTime(time) {
    this.audios.forEach(audio => audio.currentTime = time);
  }

  getDelay() {
    var times = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.audios.length; i++) {
      times.push(this.audios[i].currentTime);
    }

    var minTime = Math.min.apply(Math, times);
    var maxTime = Math.max.apply(Math, times);
    return maxTime - minTime;
  }

  setVolume(volume, audioID) {
    this.gains[audioID].gain.value = volume;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use setTimeout to sync them after a brief delay in the beginning (you may want to wait for all the audio objects to load though).

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bmAYb/35/

```
var au1 = document.getElementById('au1');
var au2 = document.getElementById('au2');
au1.volume = 1;
au2.volume = 0; //mute
au1.play();
au2.play();
var notfirstRun = false;
//sync for the first time
setTimeout(function() {
    au2.currentTime = au1.currentTime;
    au2.volume = 1;
}, 250);
```

My initial thought was to sync every x miliseconds using setInterval, but the audio pops when you do that if `volume` is set to `1` (audible).

My fiddle isn't totally in sync, but it's pretty close.  You can get it 100% in sync but you either need to mute the audio on the other tracks or deal with popping.

The code (and music in the fiddle) are from [Hungry Media](http://hungry-media.com/2010/09/synchronizing-audio-with-html5/).